# WSO2 API Analytics (3.1.0-m4) Dashboard not working

Tags: analytics, wso2-api-manager, wso2

After a few days of trial and error, I managed to connect my WSO2 API Manager with my WSO2 Analytics Worker node (both are on the same host). I first spin up the Analytics worker node and then the WSO2 API Manager. After the API Manager is up and running, I can see the following message "INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} - user admin connected" in the worker node log. After that I successfully started the Analytics Dashboard node on the same host.

I made some progress. The issue was with the DCR url https://xxxxxxxx.xx:9443/client-registration/v0.15/register
I had to change the version to v0.16.

Issue closed

Comment: Plz use a GA pack instead of using Milestone packs. You can find docker compose artifacts which helps you to up and running apim with analytics in docker. https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/v3.1.0.3/docker-compose/apim-with-analytics

Comment: What exactly is a GA pack? (Google Analytics?)

Comment: I found this post, but didn't help me too much: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730294/could-not-use-post-method-with-feign

Comment: You can download general availability packs in https://wso2.com/api-management/